# How to embed an unobtrusive flash?

Tags: html, flash

I have an embedded flash that is transparent so it looks like part of the background. I achieved that by setting wmode to transparent.

My problem is that the area underneath the flash becomes inaccessible, even though the flash is transparent. Therefore I cannot click on any links or buttons that are under the flash object.

How do I make the flash unobtrusive?

Clarifications: 
- the flash is transparent but it has an animation that shows in the background.
- wmode set to transparent lets you click the contents underneath in IE but not Firefox.

Comment: *PLEASE* don't do this kind of things. It might work on your computer. But there are many problems with flash on different platforms, and flash content overlaying html content is one of them! You will make the site unusable for users just for a fancy animation effect.

Comment: Those are customer requirements. I am hope to better alternatives?

Comment: Correcting the typo: Those are customer requirements. I am open to better alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that in your document, the `object`/`embed` that contains the Flash animation is on top of the elements you need to access. You need to put these elements on top of the Flash animation instead of the other way around.

The way to do this is to set the object's `wmode` to opaque, and use the CSS `z-index` property to set it to a `z-index` lower than the `z-index` of whatever elements you want to float over it -- you can do this in CSS or just with inline `style=""` attributes.

Here's [an example using SWFObject](http://www.pipwerks.com/lab/swfobject/z-index/2.0/index.html) to create the `object`/`embed` tags, but the same principle applies if you are just hardcoding these into your HTML.

Comment: Rendering HTML over Flash is a bit hit-and-miss, so be warned!

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know there could be such a thing as unobtrusive flash.

On a more serious note: what are you trying to accomplish with a layer of flash anyways?

I suggest taking a step back and looking at the page as a whole. If the things below the flash are needed, then make the flash go somewhere else or replace it with actual elements in the page to serve the same purpose.

Comment: Just clarified that in my edit. The flash has an animation that runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of the Flash? If it doesn't do anything visible, then you can make it 1 pixel in size and/or put it in a div that is absolutely positioned off the screen.

Comment: The flash has an animation that runs in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the answer to my own question.

There is a javascript library called [Unobtrusive Flash Objects (UFO)](http://www.bobbyvandersluis.com/ufo/index.html), which got deprecated and now is [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).

I will give it a go and report back.